# image cannot be displayed because its conain error in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("select profilepic from `profile` where id = '$pid' ");

if ($result) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $img = $row["profilepic"];
    }
}

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $img;
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Maybe the error is saying `mysql` is deprecated and discontinued in phpv7? ;)

Comment: what is the error?please specify

Comment: use echo inside if($row) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another php script to return the image data(getImage.php). Change main file as

```
<body>
<img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="175" height="200" />
</body>
```

Then getImage.php is

```
$result = mysql_query("select profilepic from `profile` where id = '$pid' ");
if ($result) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ;
$img = $row["profilepic"];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['img'];
}
```

You have to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` if you want to get values by its column name

---

```
mysql_fetch_row
```

-This function will return a row where the values will come in the order as they are defined in the SQL query, and the keys will span from 0 to one less than the number of columns selected.

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

-This function will return a row as an associative array where the column names will be the keys storing corresponding value.

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

-This function will actually return an array with both the contents of `mysql_fetch_row` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` merged into one. It will both have numeric and string keys which will let you access your data in whatever way you'd find easiest.

It is recommended to use either `_assoc` or `_row` though.